# Evaluating $I=\oint \frac{\cos(z)}{z(e^{z}-1)}dz$ along the unit circle

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

> Evaluate the following along the unit circle:
> $$I=\oint \frac{\cos(z)}{z(e^{z}-1)}dz$$

I tried doing it by $$f(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{e^{z}-1}$$

Then the integral would be: $$I=2\pi if(0)$$

The problem is that $f(0)$ gives me $\frac{1}{0}$.

So how do I solve it?

Comment: On what curve are you integrating?

Comment: Over which curve are you integrating?

Comment: the curve is a circle of radius 1

Comment: centered at origin

Comment: find residue at pole $z=0$

Comment: Note that $\frac{\cos z}{z(e^z-1)}=\frac{g(z)}{z^2}$ where $g(z):=\cos z\cdot\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ has only a removable singularity at $0$ in $\bar{\mathbb{D}}$.  Now apply Cauchy representation formula.

Answer (score 3):

This integral can be expressed with help of the residue theorem:
$$I=\oint \frac{\cos(z)}{z(e^{z}-1)}dz=2\pi i \sum_{k}\; \mathrm{Res}(f,a_k)$$
There is only one removable singularity at $z=0$ and you should be able to find the redsidue of $f$ at $z=0$, just find the coeficient at $z^1$ of the following series expansion of $z^2 f(z)$:
$$ z^2 \frac{\cos(z)}{z\left(e^{z}-1\right)}=\frac{z \cos(z)}{e^{z}-1}=1-\frac{z}{2}+O(z^2)$$ i.e.
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{\cos(z)}{z\left(e^{z}-1\right)},0\right)=-\frac{1}{2}$$
and so
$$I=\oint \frac{\cos(z)}{z(e^{z}-1)}dz=- i \pi$$

For a bit more involved calculation based on the Cauchy integral theorem see e.g. this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica/34090#34090) or using simply the residue theorem see this [one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/paths-integrals-in-the-complex-plane/36962#36962).

Comment: It is not a removable singularity at 0, is it?

Comment: @rain1  After multiplying by (z-z0)^2  (here z0 =0) f(z) becomes holomorphic at z0, i.e.  without singularity,  this is why we expand it in Taylor series. Is it clear?

Comment: I understand now, thank you

Comment: @Sebasiano Thanks for the edit, however there should be $z^2 \frac{\cos(z)}{z \left(e^z -1\right)}= \frac{z \cos(z)}{ e^z -1}=1-\frac{z}{2}+O(z^2)$, this edit made a confusion.